# read vcf files containing persian name

Tags: python, string, python-3.7, vcf-vcard

I want to read a VCF file, that contains names with persian character in UTF8 charset:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;=D8=B9=D9=84=D9=89=20=D9=85=D8=B1=D8=AD=D9=85=D8=AA=D9=89;;;
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=D8=B9=D9=84=D9=89=20=D9=85=D8=B1=D8=AD=D9=85=D8=AA=D9=89
TEL;CELL;PREF:123456789
END:VCARD
```

The code:

```
file = open('./contact.vcf', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    contacts = []
    for line in file:
        name = re.findall('FN:(.*)', line)
        nm = ''.join(name)
        if len(nm) == 0:
            continue

        data = {'name': nm.strip()}
        for lin in file:
            tel = re.findall('TEL;CELL;?(?:PREF)?:(.*)', lin)
            tel = ''.join(tel)

            if len(tel) == 0:
                continue

            tel = tel.strip()
            tel = ''.join(e for e in tel if e.isalnum())
            data['phone'] = tel
            break

        contacts.append(data)
```

When it comes to Persian names, it is empty and it done break
But there must be a more elegant way? Could anyone point me to that direction?

Answer (score 3):

The string type is **MIME quoted-printable data**.

To decode, You can use [`quopri`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html)

Decoding example:

```py
import quopri

name = '=D8=B9=D9=84=D9=89=20=D9=85=D8=B1=D8=AD=D9=85=D8=AA=D9=89'
decoded_string = quopri.decodestring(name)
print(decoded_string.decode('utf-8'))
```

[image: Python successfully decodes MIME data]